# How do I make a log scale color ramp in R?

Tags: r, colors, maps

I'm looking for a method to make a heat map in R using a log-scaled color bar. I know this is possible using ggplot, but is there another solution using the package colorRamp?

Here's an example of the colorRamp function from its help document.

```
YlOrBr <- c("#FFFFD4", "#FED98E", "#FE9929", "#D95F0E", "#993404")
filled.contour(volcano,
           color.palette = colorRampPalette(YlOrBr, space = "Lab")
```

[image]

The data I'm using are already log-transformed. How can I get the colorRamp to reflect this scale?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
YlOrBr <- c("#FFFFD4", "#FED98E", "#FE9929", "#D95F0E", "#993404")

filled.contour(log(volcano),
   color.palette = colorRampPalette(YlOrBr, space = "Lab"),
   key.axes=axis(4,at=log(pretty(volcano)),labels=pretty(volcano)))
```

[image]